# $log decorator with a service dependency causes circular dependency error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app i am writing a decorator for `$log` so that i can customize the functionality of `$log` including calling a third party service. The third party service injects `$q` for its internal activities. Now this causes circular dependency error :

**`Uncaught Error: Circular dependency: $q <- tploggerService <- $log <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope`.**

Because `qProvider` uses `exceptionHandlerProvider` which ultimately uses `logProvider` which i guess is causing this. Has any one faced similar issues while decorating and is there a solution to work around this or a different pattern to work around the problem?

Here is a simple demonstration of code, Appreciate your help:

```
///Some third party APP
angular.module('SomeThirdPartyApp', []);

    tploggerService.$inject = ['$q']; //<-- $q is a dependency

    function tploggerService ($q) {

        this.info = function (data) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(); //Doing something...
            //....
            //....
     };
}

angular.module('SomeThirdPartyApp').service('tploggerService', tploggerService);

///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
///MY APP
angular.module('decorApp', ['SomeThirdPartyApp']);

 angular.module('decorApp').config([
   '$provide', function ($provide) {
     $provide.decorator('$log', ['tploggerService','$delegate', 
       function (tploggerService, $delegate) { //<--- Injecting tpLoggerService causes circular dependency error.
         var _info = $delegate.info;
         //It is no different even if we use $injector
         $delegate.info = function(){
             var args; //doing something with the arguments basically formatting massaging it.
             var customlogmessage; //doing something with args

             tploggerService.info(customlogmessage);
             _info.apply(null, args);
         }
         return $delegate;
       }]);
   }]);
```

- [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/dizikoka/8/edit)
- [Plnkr after $q removed](http://plnkr.co/edit/BdsasOhkM2o7yWomyUio?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get $q from inside of your service:

```
function tploggerService ($injector) {
    var $q;
    this.info = function (data) {
        $q = $injector.get('$q');
        var deferred = $q.defer(); //Yes using defered object. some this performs some actions and some internal stuffs.

        //Doing something...
    };
}
```

[Updated Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mcraXcbGKO8XKLvEOqTX?p=info)

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that. But that kind  of look hacky and also i should have mentioned i do not have much control over the third party service especially if the solution is hacky because the real dependencies are not advertised with the use of $injector. Also the fact that the instance of q is created inside the function and not in the `tploggerService` constructor which if you do will give the same circular dep error. If you actually use injector [you could do this way as well](http://plnkr.co/edit/eYskveTIQdbUDJWsSiRB?p=preview).

Comment: Fair enough! I'm not sure how you're going to get around modifying the third party source since it seems fundamentally incompatible as a decorator for $log. I'm not the sharpest bit here though so I will continue to watch this question with interest.

Comment: Yeah... true.. I had the same thoughts as you had but doing it inside the decorator function. But seemed hacky. Appreaciate ur answer though..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can only $delegate in the `$provider.decorator()`, I think if you should put the bussiness logic in the decorator function other than using an inject way.For example:

```
$provider.decorator('$log',function($delegate){
  $delegate.info = function(){
     var args = Array.prototype.slice(arguments);
     var deferred = $q.defer(); //Doing something...
     $delegate.info.apply(null,args);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i dont think you are right. Because you can inject what you want actually. In my example if you remove the dependency on `$q` from tploggerService. You can see that it works.