# How to inject toaster library into logging module without getting circular dependency error in exception handler

Tags: angularjs

I have added the AngularJS-Toaster library to my index.html:

```
<link href="lib/angularjs-toaster/toaster.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/angularjs-toaster/toaster.min.js"></script>
<toaster-container 
  toaster-options="{'position-class': 'toast-bottom-center'}">
</toaster-container>
```

And in my angular app:

```
//app.js
(function () {
    angular
        .module('app', ['toaster','blocks.logger',/*etc*/]);
})();

//blocks/logger/logger.module.js
(function () {
    angular.module('blocks.logger', ['toaster']);
})();

//blocks/logger/logger.js
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('blocks.logger')
    .factory('logger', logger);

logger.$inject = ['$log', 'toaster'];

function logger($log, toaster) {

    var service = {
        error: error,
        info: info,
        success: success,
        warning: warning,

        log: $log.log  // straight to console;
    };

    return service;

    function error(message, title, data) {
        toaster.error({ title: title || 'Error', body: message, timeout: 6000 });
        $log.error(message, data);
    }
    //etc
}());
```

But when I do this I get a circular dependency error from the injector: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep]`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I have discovered that the problem is related to an exception handler that I  have used:

```
//code lifted from https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos (modular)
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('blocks.exception')
        .provider('exceptionHandler', exceptionHandlerProvider)
        .config(config);

    function exceptionHandlerProvider() {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        this.config = {
            appErrorPrefix: undefined
        };

        this.configure = function (appErrorPrefix) {
            this.config.appErrorPrefix = appErrorPrefix;
        };

        this.$get = function () {
            return { config: this.config };
        };
    }

    function config($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', extendExceptionHandler);
    }

    //function extendExceptionHandler($delegate, exceptionHandler, logger) {
    function extendExceptionHandler($delegate, exceptionHandler) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            var appErrorPrefix = exceptionHandler.config.appErrorPrefix || '';
            var errorData = { exception: exception, cause: cause };
            var logMessage = appErrorPrefix + exception.message;
            $delegate(exception, cause);

            //logger.error(logMessage, errorData);
        };
    }
})();
```

By commenting out the use of the logger, I can use logging elsewhere. But I'd like to use my logger here too. So what is going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution - use `$injector` in the exception handler:

```
//blocks/exception/exception.module.js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('blocks.exception', ['blocks.logger']);
})();

//blocks/exception/exceptionHandlerProvider.js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('blocks.exception')
        .config(exceptionConfig);

    exceptionConfig.$inject = ['$provide'];

    function exceptionConfig($provide) {
        $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", exceptionHandler);
    }

    exceptionHandler.$inject = ['$delegate', '$injector'];

    function exceptionHandler($delegate, $injector) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            var logger = $injector.get('logger');
            logger.error(exception.message);
            $delegate(exception, cause);
        };
    }

})();
```

References:

[$log decorator with a service dependency causes circular dependency error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416924/log-decorator-with-a-service-dependency-causes-circular-dependency-error)

[Angular style guide - exceptions](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#exception-handling)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because you are calling the module dependency from `app` module but actually you are using it on `blocks.logger`.

```
angular.module('blocks.logger', ['toaster']);
```

instead of

```
 // remove toaster dependency
 angular.module('app', ['toaster','blocks.logger',/*etc*/]);
```

Comment: I've incorporated your suggestion and have now discovered that my problem lies with an exception handler - see my edit