# Circular dependency found when trying to add toastr to custom logger

Tags: typescript, toastr

I have been trying to use an approach demoed by John Papa where I have an exception handler and this exception handler calls into a logger class. This logger can then take different action like logging to the console, database or a toastr message. I have it all working but what I can't figure out is as soon as I add the toastr reference I get the below message.

```
[$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $rootScope <- $q <- $$AnimateRunner <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- toastr <- logger <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope
```

I am using TypeScript to set this up and the only other place I have a toastr reference is in the model setup where I pass the dependancy in to the logger and I also have a config function exposed where it sets up the toaster config.

```
toastrConfig.$inject = ['toastrConfig'];
/** @ngInject */
export function toastrConfig(toastrConfig: ToastrOptions) {
// var toastrConfig = toastr.options;
(<any>toastrConfig).allowHtml = true;
toastrConfig.timeOut = 3000;
toastrConfig.positionClass = 'toast-top-right';
toastrConfig.progressBar = true;
}


angular
    .module('blocks.logger', ['toastr'])
    .service('logger', Logger);
```

Then I try and do something as simple as this:

```
export class Logger implements ILogger {
static $inject: Array<string> = ['toastr'];
constructor(private toastr) { }

log(...args: any[]) {
    ////this.$log.log(args);
}

error(message: string, data?: {}, title?: string) {
    toastr.error(message);
}
```

I can't see where I would be doubling up the dependency. Any thoughts? By the error it looks like I am looping back to $rootScope but I am not sure how. I am guessing it has something to do with out the exceptionHandlerProvider is setup, so here that is.

```
import { ILogger } from '../logger/logger';

// The exceptionHandler provider handles any unhandled exceptions and logs the exception to the console window
 // then calls the Logger to log the exception to the server side

 export interface IExceptionHandlerConfig {
appErrorPrefix: string
}
export class ExceptionHandlerProvider {
static $inject: Array<string> = [];
constructor() { }

config: IExceptionHandlerConfig = {
    appErrorPrefix: undefined
}

configure(appErrorPrefix: any) {
    this.config.appErrorPrefix = appErrorPrefix;
}

$get: () => { config: IExceptionHandlerConfig } = () => { return { config: this.config }; }
}

exceptionHandlerProviderConfig.$inject = ['$provide'];
export function exceptionHandlerProviderConfig($provide:     ng.auto.IProvideService) {
$provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', extendExceptionHandler);
}

extendExceptionHandler.$inject = ['$delegate', 'exceptionHandler', 'logger'];

function extendExceptionHandler($delegate: ng.IExceptionHandlerService,
exceptionHandlerProvider: ExceptionHandlerProvider,
logger: ILogger) {
return function (exception: any, cause: any) {
    var appErrorPrefix = exceptionHandlerProvider.config.appErrorPrefix || '';
    var errorData = { exception: exception, cause: cause };
    exception.message = appErrorPrefix + exception.message;
    $delegate(exception, cause);    // Logs to the console

    /**
     * Could add the error to a service's collection,
     * add errors to $rootScope, log errors to remote web server,
     * or log locally. Or throw hard. It is entirely up to you.
     * throw exception;
     *
     * @example
     *     throw { message: 'error message we added' };
     */
    logger.error(exception.message, errorData);
};
}
```

Comment: Not sure if anyone is looking at this anymore but when I don't inject 'logger' into the extendExceptionHandler I don't get this error anymore. However, this means the global exception catch can't use my logger to log globally caught exceptions. 

But it lets the logger with with toastr work just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject toaster library into logging module without getting circular dependency error in exception handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584687/how-to-inject-toaster-library-into-logging-module-without-getting-circular-depen)

Answer (score 0):

In your logger class you have:

```
error(message: string, data?: {}, title?: string) {
    toastr.error(message);
}
```

But `toastr` is defined in the scope of the class, so you'll to need refer to it by:

```
this.toastr.error(message);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected that but that was not the issue causing the circle reference.

Comment: Ok, I will look at this later and see if I see anything else.